# a method validating objects from different roots repeats most of checks

Tags: java, lambda, instanceof

please is there a way how to make the code more concise -
to avoid repeating similar/same actions -
I have a method doing object validations, but most parameters
are similar/same, like using some sort of lambda expression for that,
but objects are not from the same tree.

My use-case is like this:

```
validate.( car );
```

and somewhere else I do:

```
validate.( person );
```

Right now I am doing the validation like this:

```
public boolean validate( Object obj ) {
  if ( obj instanceof Car ) {

    Car car = (Car) obj;
    if ( car.getAge() <= 0 ) return false;
    // many other checks which are repeated below

  } else if ( obj instanceof Person ) {

    Person person = (Person) obj;
    if ( person.getAge() <= 0 ) return false;
    // many other check which are repeating those above

  }
  // here I would like to do checks for both objects, but objects are from different roots

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [method overloading](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_overloading.asp) :

```
public boolean validate(Car car) {
    if ( car.getAge() <= 0 ) return false;
    return validate((Master)car);
}
public boolean validate(Person p) {
    if ( p.getAge() <= 0 ) return false;
    return validate((Master)p);
}
public boolean validate(Master m) {
    // common validations
    return true;
}
```

Master is the common parent of Person and Car (I assume there is a common parent interface/class).

Answer (score 0):

### "Do not"s:

1. First of all, I would strictly suggest you to try your best to avoid designing your method as you are doing it now;
2. `Person` and `Car` have nothing in common from the logical, modelling, or conceptual perspective. Nor they do share any similar characteristics in the real life;
3. Do not accept `Object` as an argument in your method. You will have hard times of managing your bugs and/or maintaining unpredictable behaviour.

### "Do"s:

1. Define your method by following [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle);
2. Consider from your model object perspective - what your method should be as a *behaviour*? what *ONE* problem it should solve?
3. Try to separate concerns in their respective classes/files/block-units and try not to overlap them.

---

If you want to your method to *behave* based on what is the actual instance of the argument, best way is to use `instanceof` checks.

What you can do instead, however, is to design some proper inheritance and accept a supertype, as a method argument. Then polymorphism would kick in and you will only have one logic in your method.

Comment: Thanks, those are entities, and my model is probably not optimal, so I will create abstract superclass and both objects will inherit from that.